# How to change Attribute Type

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I have created an attribute **product-pv** like below.

[image]

Using the following code,

```
function proccess_add_attribute($attribute){
global $wpdb;
//check_admin_referer( 'woocommerce-add-new_attribute' );

if (empty($attribute['attribute_type'])) { $attribute['attribute_type'] = 'text';}
if (empty($attribute['attribute_orderby'])) { $attribute['attribute_orderby'] = 'menu_order';}
if (empty($attribute['attribute_public'])) { $attribute['attribute_public'] = 0;}

if ( empty( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) || empty( $attribute['attribute_label'] ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', __( 'Please, provide an attribute name and slug.', 'woocommerce' ) );
} elseif ( ( $valid_attribute_name = valid_attribute_name( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) && is_wp_error( $valid_attribute_name ) ) {
        return $valid_attribute_name;
} elseif ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', sprintf( __( 'Slug "%s" is already in use. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce' ), sanitize_title( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) );
}

$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );

do_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', $wpdb->insert_id, $attribute );

flush_rewrite_rules();
delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
return true;}
```

Here **product-pv** attribute shows a select box but what I want is a textbox. Then I created an attribute **test** manually. It shows a textbox like below. So is it possible to create a textbox programatically?

[image]